# Mysql error 1064, possibly noobish

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my first website using mysql working. When I attempt to make the code to auto-create the tables on install there are errors. I have checked other posts with the same error id, but none of their solutions are applicable.

```
CREATE TABLE users (primarykeyid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY, username VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(32), email VARCHAR(40), salt VARCHAR(512))
```

But I get the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY_KEY, username VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(32), email VARCHAR(40), salt' at line 1
```

I Do not know what is causing the error as all of the mysql looks valid to me. However, I am new to mysql so please forgive me if this is a noobish mistake.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the underscore in the PRIMARY KEY. `PRIMARY_KEY` => `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Thank you, looks good :) I will accept this answer (unless a better one comes along, but I am not sure how that could happen), when stackoverflow lets me :)

Comment: Damn you don't know how many times that happened to me back in the days. You are welcome.